# Make many txt files into 1 file without copying the content of files

Tags: php, mysql

I have many files that txt documnets and its hard for me to open every files and clear 4frist line of my txt documents and copy to a global file is any way or any php code to open every file in the folder and clear 4 frist line and make  a Collection of this file in a global file ........

Comment: yes, there is way... what you have tried? please show us your code so that we can help you...

Comment: @babakfaghihian : DON'T SHOUT... Now think, if I told you to do manually, what you would have done? Think that in programming language. Find number of files in folder... Start loop, read file, exclude first four lines, now start writing in main file... done....

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to handle file content with PHP you could use **[exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)** and use Unix Command to do so .

```
cat partialFile.xml >> HUGE-FILE.xml
```

Comment: this will bring all data in one file... OP don't want first four line of each file...